# SQL Server Management Studio 2017 - Tabs Not Repainting

Tags: ssms, prompt, redgate

I'm having a minor issue (more annoying than anything else) in SQL Server Management Studio 2017 the workspace in my tabs (when I have more than one open, which I almost always do) aren't repainting properly. The content from one tab bleeds into another.

To correct this I close the tab and open it again (on a file open), move the cursor up and down (when I click into another tab) or click back and forth between 2 tabs until the content is correct.

As I said, it's more of an annoyance than anything else, and I do have a work around, but I'm concerned because SSMS asked me if I wanted to save the file when I opened an existing file today and found it had the wrong content and closed it. If I wasn't paying attention I might have overwritten the file.

As an FYI, I am using the most recent version of Red Gate SQL Prompt (10.4) which I uninstalled and reinstalled after I downloaded and installed SSMS 18.4.

Thanks in advance, Peter

Answer (score 1):

I remember this problem on an older version of SSMS 18, but pretty sure it was fixed in SSMS 18.1 or 18.2 (which ever version came out after the probkem was introduced). Also your title says SSMS 2017 but you close by saying you're using 18.4, so I've assumed you're using 18.4.

If you are still getting the problem, try disabling hardware graphics acceleration: `Tools` -> `Options` -> `Environment/General` -> `Use hardware graphics acceleration if available`, as that *used* to be the cause if I recall correctly.